The standalone package and custom sty files
I wanted to use the standalone package to speed up the compilation of my large project, I landed on this files structure:
.
├── main.tex
├── Includes.sty
├── Language.sty
├── assets
│   └── img
│   └── pdf
└── src
    ├── sec1
    │   └── sec1.tex
    └── sec2
        └── sec2.tex

each tex file in the src directory is in a separate directory, so I keep the compilation results clean.
as you can see I'm using a custom Language.sty file to include all the necessary packages and commands I need to use across all tex files. and I'm having extreme trouble in compiling the results.
When I compile the files, it works when the files are simple (i.e. don't have an custom commands from the sty files) but when I start using the commands there it break, one such problem gives this error:
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ..._xpg_inline_lang \xpg@otherlanguageLaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...olyglossia@lang@settextdirection:nnLaTeX
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \polyglossia@langsetupLaTeX
Argument of \__prop_map_tokens:nw has an extra }.
<inserted text>LaTeX
Paragraph ended before \__prop_map_tokens:nw was complete.
<to be read again>LaTeX

I'm using XeLaTeX on MacOS, and LaTeX workshop on VScode.
maybe I'm approaching this like a C/C++ project approach, any suggestions?
The main.tex file has this preamble:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    twoside,
    a4paper,
    top   =2.4cm,
    bottom=2.4cm,
    inner=2.4cm,  
    outer=2.4cm,  
    marginparwidth=2cm,
    marginparsep=0.2cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{Includes}
\usepackage{Language}

\usepackage[
    subpreambles=true
]{standalone}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

\import{src/sec1/}{sec1}
\import{src/sec2/}{sec2}

\end{document}

and the src tex files have this preamble:
\documentclass[class=article, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[
    twoside,
    a4paper,
    top   =2.4cm,
    bottom=2.4cm,
    inner=2.4cm,  
    outer=2.4cm,  
    marginparwidth=2cm,
    marginparsep=0.2cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{../../Includes}
\usepackage{../../Language}

\begin{document}
\end{document}

I also added these in my custom sty files, but I'm not sure if these are needed:
\ifdefined\LANGUAGESTY
\else
\newcommand{\LANGUAGESTY}{}
% ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- %
% all the defines and the command needed are here, for example:
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\textenglish{#1}}
% ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- %
\fi % \LANGUAGESTY


generally, a flat directory structure is most straightforward and you don't want to 'keep the compilation results clean'! are you sure standalone and import are compatible? combining them strikes me as an invitation to trouble, but I haven't actually tried it. \usepackage isn't meant to take a path. It's supposed to take a package name.  \providecommand would be better than \ifdefined. but a .sty should be input only once regardless how many times it is loaded, so you shouldn't need to do this at all.

beyond generalities, it is hard to diagnose the specific problem except to say that it certainly depends on code you've not shown as it involves a package not evident anywhere. can you provide a proper non-working example to reproduce the first error? and please provide the complete error message - the ones you show are only fragments. that particular error will say that the command shown on the top line of the message is undefined (telling you which macro is not defined) and will tell you the line number on which it is used.

(i removed the \ifdefined stuff) the reason I used import and standalone is because an overleaf example uses them, they work for a simple case.
so i should move all the tex files into the root directory, my case is that all of the files share the same preamble, but, I would like to compile each one separately, since I want to look at each chapter alone, and then compile all the files into one

can't you just \include{} each chapter into the main file and put \includeonly{} in your preamble? perhaps standalone and import can be combined, but I'd only try to do that if I had a really good reason to do it. nothing in your question suggested you had such a reason ;). incidentally, be very careful with tex \if...s in preambles if you use standalone (and probably the same goes for import).

oh, I just realised you have the subpreambles option and then use \usepackage{../../}. even if that was wise in general, I don't think it can work here. I forget exactly what standalone does here, but I doubt it tries to resolve relative path names.

the main reason i split up the document into files, is that the main document is large and takes 7 seconds to compile, the smaller files are much faster to compile, I only want to compile the whole document when the chapters are finished, so using \include{} doesn't help much

or is \includeonly{} used to actually just compile the appropriate chapters?

yes it does. that's precisely what \includeonly{} does in your preamble. this is the standard way of managing, say, a dissertation.

oh i see, i think this should solve it, thanks

As recommended by @cfr, use \include and \includeonly (standard LaTeX). import and standalone do not work together in this way: \imported files may not contain \documentclass commands. Maybe the subfiles package comes closest to what you want to achieve, but I don't recommend it if the main purpose is to reduce compilation time. Moreover, (La)TeX uses auxiliary files to transport information between different parts of the document. If you hide them, some things will not work properly. If you want to stay 'clean', use one of the tools that remove auxiliary files (clean up).

but don't remove auxiliary files between compilation runs as they contain information required on subsequent runs. if you use something like latexmk, you could clean them out, but you would greatly increase compilation time.

It might be worth checking why you document takes that long to compile. For ordinary text, it is fast. Maybe you have some complicated code in some parts that could be sped up by pre-compilation (standalone package). Or sometimes it helps to use \savebox if you repeatedly typeset the same code fragements.

the document uses 3 languages and has many many diagrams and code listings among other stuff, so the standalone trick might work better than savebox. but its complicated to use, do you have any good resources?
